# Search hibernate entities by prototype

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I've got JPA entity class like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String lastName;
   private String firstName;
   private String country;
   private String gender; 
...
//setters and getters are omitted
}
```

I need searching method like this `List<Person> findAll(Person searchCriteria)`

Usage example:

```
Person criteria1 = new Person();
criteria1.setFristName("John");
criteria1.setCountry("Usa");

//returns all John from Usa with any lastName
List<Person> searchingResult = findAll(criteria1);

Person criteria2 = new Person();
criteria2.setGender("m");
criteria2.setCountry("Holland");

//returns all man from Holland
List<Person> anotherSearchingResult = findAll(criteria2);
```

My idea of findAll method is

```
String query = "select * from person where ";
if(criteria.getLastName() != null) query+= "last_name = "+ criteria.getLastName();
if(criteria.getGender() != null) query+= "gender = "+ criteria.getGender();
etc
List<Person> = session.execute(query);
```

But this is so ugly and looks like some overhead.
Can anyone help me to invite that `findAll` method more prettily? I can use any java technology or framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're looking for a *prototype*? Hibernate has a handy `Example` criteria just for this, so if you don't mind tying yourself to the Hibernate API, try this example from the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-examples):

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
cat.setSex('F');
cat.setColor(Color.BLACK);
List results = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .add( Example.create(cat) )
    .list();
```

It specifically says:

> Version properties, identifiers and associations are ignored. By default, null valued properties are excluded.

Which is just what you appear to want.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Hibernate Criteria. You can stack restrictions as such:

```
List cats = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .add( Restrictions.like("name", "Fritz%") )
    .add( Restrictions.or(
        Restrictions.eq( "age", new Integer(0) ),
        Restrictions.isNull("age")
    ) )
    .list();
```

Restrictions refer to annotated variables in the class. Take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html).

Comment: I think the OP's point was that he has lots of properties of which only some are set (and thus needed for the query). Adding them manually is a lot of work.