# Check if rows exist in table

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

Consider this code. This code inserts the row to the database if it is not found, then only updates it if the row is found. The updateNode() method gives the entity some values based on the user input, so I called it in both cases.

```
session.beginTransaction();
node = (Node)session.createQuery("from Node").uniqueResult();
if (node == null) {
    node = new Node();
    updateNode();
    session.save(node);
} else {
    updateNode();
}
session.getTransaction.commit();
```

Is there a better way of checking if rows exist in the table aside from using queries?

Comment: Yes. Don't check first!

Comment: @Strawberry
 can you explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Is the cat alive or dead?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger's_cat) You don't know without checking it, so you'll have to execute the query in the database.

I assume your question is about to avoid writing such a query manually, but rather letting Hibernate do it itself. Then you may want to look at [querying by example/prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790052/search-hibernate-entities-by-prototype).

Regardless of the approach taken, keep concurrency issues in mind though; you may want to apply some unique constraints and/or optimistic/pessimistic locks.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to find out if something already exists in the database is to query it. However you do not need a separate query. You need only one query and not two thanks to mysql's [INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) feature. And it doesn't need any additional java coding either.

If you want to do this with hibernate it will have to be a custom query and you will need to return the inserted row id with LAST_INSERT_ID in your query.

Comment: is this possible with hibernate query language? And how about other DBMS? Is this feature only specific to mysql?

Comment: This feature is not available in Postgresql upto 9.4 but I understand it's scheduled for 9.5. sqlite does not have the feature but it has an INSERT OR IGNORE feature which can be immediately followed up an UPDATE. Donno about others

Comment: but no hibernate specific way of doing it?

Comment: no hibernate doesn't have anything built into handle it AFAIK. Updated the answer. You will need a custom query. @SQLInsert