# Can I query in hibernate via DTO/Entity not by single fields

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a question regarding querying in hibernate. If there is a way to search without specifying an where cause explicitly?

So what I mean is: let's say I have a search form with 10 columns that are bound to my dto fields. So the user can fill some of them and left the rest as nulls. And now I would like to search only by fields that are specified (filled) and left the nulls behind (they doesn't matter).

So the query would be like this:

```
select e 
from entity e 
where e.entity = e.searchedCriteriaEntityGivenInDTO
```

Or a better example via jpg: I'd like to have all sample entities without specifying "where number, where name, where firstanme", but over my dto by "where dtoFields". As mentioned the nulls should be ignored.

Thanks a lot in advance.

[image: sample]

[EDIT]: Thanks to Dragon I have a great solution how to do it, but I have one more question: What about I have 2 row's, I can search? My query should look like:

```
select e 
from example e, 
where (e.entity = example) OR (e.entity = example2);
```

I tried to put the

```
session.createCriteria(MyEntity.class).add(Example.create(myEntityExample))
```

into an OR-Predicate but it seems it does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is better to use [hibernate criteria](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_criteria_queries.htm). You can add some conditions to ignore null fields.

Comment: Not sure if you can do this, but you can make a metod which will return a criteria with only non null fields and you'll be able to execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do it with DTOs, but you can use a [prototype (example)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22790637/4754790) entity instance for it:

```
MyEntity myEntityExample = new MyEntity();
myEntityExample.setNumber(12);
myEntityExample.setName("AA");
myEntityExample.setFirstName("BB");
List<MyEntity> results = session.createCriteria(MyEntity.class)
    .add(Example.create(myEntityExample))
    .list();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exacly what I needed :)